# Apple BootCamp Driver Issues (Sound/Wifi)

Tags: boot-camp

I am trying to install Apple BootCamp support software for a MacBook Pro (mid 2015) on Windows 8.1. BootCamp partitions and installs Windows fine, but when I reboot and install the support software, there is still no sound or wifi. I.e. Drivers, which is basically what the support software is, don't seem to work. Tried several times. Please help.

Comment: Reworded... Please help...

Comment: Have you tried installing the drivers from boot camp folder, after you have logged into windows ?